# What is the difference between Samsung EVO and PRO SSD

Tags: ssd

There are considereble price differences between EVO and PRO series of Samsun SSDs.
Is it worth it to buy a PRO series?

What is the difference between EVO and PRO in first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the main difference is hard drive durability/life time. Depending on the series of the Samsung SSD, the pro sometimes have faster read and write. The newest [850 series in particular](http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Samsung-850-Evo-250GB-vs-Samsung-850-Pro-256GB/2977vs2385) does not seem to be all that different in performance with the exception of write speed.

In general, the EVO series are going to be much better value, and usually the better option. Personally, if I was willing to spend the money on a 850 Pro series, I would just go with the [960 evo NVMe M.2 SSD](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/462rxr/samsung-960-evo-series-250gb-pcie-nvme-m2-internal-ssd-mz-v6e250bw) if you have the interface to support it. It's MSRP is lower and it [actually outperforms the 850 pro by a huge margin](http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Samsung-850-Pro-256GB-vs-Samsung-960-Evo-NVMe-PCIe-M2-250GB/2385vsm200373).

EDIT:
I double checked and actually the [970 EVO](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/dkHRsY/samsung-970-evo-250gb-m2-2280-solid-state-drive-mz-v7e250bw) is the latest of that series and it's market value is lower than the 960 and faster to boot. My points don't change, however.